# Assigning roles to paths dynamically in symfony2

Tags: php, security, symfony, acl

I'm attempting to implement access security to certain URLs using an existing users/groups/roles system in a Symfony2 app.  I'm trying to puzzle out the best way to integrate this into Symfony's access_control (or potentially even bin it and manage access control manually).

The problem is I have a url (say, /example) that right now is accessible by anyone in the ADMIN group. These groups then have finer grained roles assigned to each. So, say, the ADMIN group may have a EXAMPLE_GET, EXAMPLE_POST roles, etc. But other groups may only have EXAMPLE_GET, so I need to take the User object, grab the associated groups, get the roles, then work out if that user can access the URL using the http method they're trying to use.

Initially, I wanted to just manually add the group names as roles (in the context of symfony security roles), then use `getRoles()` in the user object to check if that person had access to the correct group to access it. However, it turns out list of groups I have isn't finite, and more can be created at any point, so I need to avoid hard coding the groups in if possible.

Can anyone suggest the best approach to take with this? Or point me in the direction of any documentation around how to achieve this or something similar?  The key point is that I *can't* hard code specific security groups as roles in security.yml, because people need to be able to create more groups without having to manually add the new group name to the access_control list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sound like a `VoterInterface` woulde fit best here: 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters.html

I would not try to do this directly with firewalls (path based approach)

Only require a generic User to be logged in by protecting your resources against IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY grant with the firewalls in security.yml. This would lock out any not logged in user.

The voter implementation will check all the permissions and then return a grant or not.

In your controller method just check for the needed grant like this:

```
public function showAction($id)
    {
        // get a Post instance
        $post = ...;

        // keep in mind that this will call all registered security voters
        $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('view', $post, 'Unauthorized access!');

        return new Response('<h1>'.$post->getName().'</h1>');
    }
```

Comment: Thanks - it looks like the voter route is the best option. ACL was far too overkill for what was needed, and backporting it to support millions of existing objects would have been a logistical nightmare